# How to allow user to login only from the office?

Tags: php, ip, authorization

I have a web application that has simple user/pass authorisation. The client wants to allow his employees to use it only from the office.

What are the best ways to do it?

- Create the allowed IP list and see if user's IP match it?
- Activate/deactivate users records in DB when they come and when they leave the office (add this work for a manager)?
- Maybe configure browser to send some specific data to the server (User-agent)?
- Something else?

*Web app is written on PHP, PostgreSQL*

Comment: Put the app on a local (internal) environment which is firewalled?

Comment: Hosted local, only private IPs (10.x.x.x) allowed. Or firewalled as mentioned before.

Comment: @FDL, The application works for 50 other clients, it updates each week and has connection to our other internet services. We need control of the file and DB systems, so we can't install it locally.

Comment: If the offices have fixed IP addresses, that should be a pretty simple filter. If they have dynamically changing addresses, it may be a little more complex. Can you detail the scenario and possibilities more?

Comment: @deceze, I don't know what type of IP addresses they will have in their office, I'm still searching for the best solution. The scenario is simple: user shouldn't be able to login at home - he should login only at the office. We can change backend/frontent and configure their office computers (if that would help).

Comment: If you have freedom to configure their office computers, maybe client-side SSL certificates are an option if you're really determined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy way to see if the user has logged in to the web-app from the office computer:

[Manually add some string to browser's config parameter](http://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/) 'user-agent' and check `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` if it contains it.

For example 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0 OFFICE'

Of course it's absolutely unsafe, but it can be suitable for a client.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of restricting access via IP, you want to use something that's actually secure.

Username and password over an HTTPS connection should at least be unsniffable, but you might want to look in to client SSL certificates. They can be configured in Apache or other web server software. If username/password authentication is not enough, this is the next (and perhaps final) step up.

UPDATE:

That said, what many application providers will do is provide a method for subscribers to implement an ACL for their accounts. You can even force people to consider their ACL before allowing them to access your services. Think of it this way:

> An account is set up in your system allowing login from anywhere. Upon
>   creation, the ACL is UNSET. User logs in and is immediately directed
>   to an ACL setup page, where they must provide either an IP address or
>   range or subnet associated with their account. You can be clever and
>   pre-populate things with their existing IP address or subnet, perhaps
>   even looking things up at ARIN to see if their IP is in a network
>   assigned to the company name on their account. Once the ACL is set (or
>   they have, despite your warnings, confirmed that they want to keep
>   their ACL open), they can access your services. If they try log in
>   from elsewhere, they (and you) are notified via email (or SMS or
>   whatever) of an attempted breach. If they no longer have access to
>   their ACL-listed IPs (i.e. IP renumbering due to a new upstream
>   Internet provider and bad planning), they can call your phone support
>   who will validate them by other means. FAX confirmation perhaps,
>   because that's SO secure...

A user-managed ACL is not a "sure-fire" way, but it may be sufficiently effective for your needs, and it will certainly instill a sense in your customers that you have their best interests at heart.